# How to Use a Different Port on Peer.js Server

Tags: webrtc

My webhost has said the port 9000 is not available for an install of Peer.js Server.

Peer.js:
https://peerjs.com/

Peer.js Server:
https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server

My webhost says, 'Only the standard ports, 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS' are available.

Does that mean I cannot install Peer.js Server on my webhost website?

Do I have to change all the 9000 to 80? Is that possible when only port 80 is all I am allowed on my webhost website? (I am still in the early learning phase of Node.js and websites.)

The webhost is Winhost, the basic option, if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually run a Peer.js server using Express and specify whatever port you'd like.
Try this:

```
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const expressPort = 9000;
const expressServer = app.listen(expressPort);
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(expressServer);

app.use('/peerjs', peerServer);
```

So you can hit the Peer.js server on the specified endpoint /peerjs

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to run it on 80/443. Those are already in use by your web server, Nginx/Apache. You should grab a minimal VPS (virtual private server) and use that to run your Peer.js server.